# How to make localization provider flutter app with dark and light theme provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, themes, provider

In flutter have multi provider but are there have easier way? At least please give me examples.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) =\> MultiProvider(
providers: \[
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) =\> ThemeProvider(),
),
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
   create: (context) =\> LocaleProvider(),
 ),
\],
builder: (context, child) {
final themeProvider = Provider.of\<ThemeProvider\>(context);
// final localeProvider = Provider.of\<LocaleProvider\>(context);
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 locale: localeProvider.locale,
 supportedLocales: L10n.all,
 localizationsDelegates: const \[
   AppLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
 \],
);
},
);
```

I want to add my flutter app two language and dark, light mode.